# Google Maps API v2 newLatLngBounds using percentage padding throws error in Multi-Window mode

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, multi-window

I am animating the camera to a `LatLngBounds` with a padding set based on the **percentage** of the device `width` so that it works on small devices.

This works even on small devices with 4inch displays, however it fails in multi-window mode in Android 7.0 and devices that support multi-window mode before that, eg. Galaxy S7.

I get the following exception on devices in multi-window mode:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error using newLatLngBounds(LatLngBounds, int, int, int): View size is too small after padding is applied.
```

Here is the suspect code:

```
private void animateCamera() {

    // ...

    // Create bounds from positions
    LatLngBounds bounds = latLngBounds(positions);

    // Setup camera movement
    final int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    final int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    final int padding = (int) (width * 0.40); // offset from edges of the map in pixels
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, padding);

    mMap.animateCamera(cu);
}
```

How can I properly set the padding in `newLatLngBounds` to work on all device widths and in multi-window mode?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution is to choose the minimum metric between width and height, since in Multi-window mode the height can be smaller than the width:

```
private void animateCamera() {

    // ...

    // Create bounds from positions
    LatLngBounds bounds = latLngBounds(positions);

    // Setup camera movement
    final int width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
    final int height = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
    final int minMetric = Math.min(width, height);
    final int padding = (int) (minMetric * 0.40); // offset from edges of the map in pixels
    CameraUpdate cu = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, width, height, padding);

    mMap.animateCamera(cu);
}
```